# nuget install package from code unable to resolve

Tags: c#, nuget

Perplexed why I my NuGet package with content that I want transformed wasn't working with my .net core console application I decided to try and look at a different way of doing this. One thought I had was to use linqpad to just load my nuget package and do the transforms myself (since it wasn't that much). A quick google search and I see that Nuget has a Core package. I add that to my linqpad query and come up with this

```
void Main()
{
    const string myPackageToInstall = "My.Custom.ServiceTemplate";
    const string installPath = @"C:\Git\Path\To\PickupsScheduler";

    var repositoryFactory = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default;
    var sources = new List<PackageSource>{
        new PackageSource("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json", "official"),
        new PackageSource(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages", "local"),
    };

    var repository = AggregateRepository.Create(repositoryFactory, sources, true);
    var template = repository.FindPackage(myPackageToInstall).Dump(myPackageToInstall, 0);

    var packageManager = new PackageManager(repository, installPath);
    packageManager.InstallPackage(template, false, true, false);
}
```

however when I run that I would expect the same output that I get when I do it through Visual Studio 2017 (success but no content files added..or even hopefully content files that get transformed but that's just hopeful wishing) Running the code in linqpad I get `Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.0.0)'`

The dependencies I have in my package are:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.NETCore.App
- NLog
- NLog.Extensions.Logging
- PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService

and I just have a few content files to help me out. Any ideas why I'm getting the exception?

**EDIT**

adding my nuspec just for clarity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Custom.ServiceTemplate</id>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <authors>Robert Snyder</authors>
    <owners>Robert Snyder</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Template used to build a barebone windows service with a timer</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.0">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.NETCore.App" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="NLog" version="[4.5.0-rc06, )" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="NLog.Extensions.Logging" version="[1.0.0-rtm-rc7, )" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService" version="2.0.6" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="appsettings.json" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="nlog.config" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="NLog.xsd" buildAction="None"/>
      <files include="**/*.cs.pp" buildAction="Compile"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="appsettings.json" target="content"/>
    <file src="nlog.config" target="content"/>
    <file src="NLog.xsd" target="content"/>
    <file src="**/*.cs.pp" target="content"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet Core package is an outdated one and does not support or have any clue about .NET Core projects and the package reference restore style.

If you wanted to do stuff from the code, consider using the newer dlls (versions 4.x). 
For your case, you'd likely want to be using NuGet.Protocol to do these things.

Now back to your original problem.

There are some new concepts in package reference. Content vs ContentFiles etc.

Are you using xdt transforms?
If so, refer to the following [issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5954) for that support in PackageReference.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/master/XDTransformExample)

Comment: no i'm doing source file transforms. All it is really doing is replacing the namespace of the classes.

Comment: These transformations are done by the .NET Core SDK/build normally. 

The transformations will only happen on build/publish time. 
I assume the folder structure is correct?
ex.
cs/tfm/*.pp

Comment: in the nupkg it is correct.. after install none of the files get copied over. From what i've read that is a known bug

Comment: This is not going to happen during install. 

It's not supposed to happen during install, because it can leave the user in an inconsistent state if they don't remove a package a certain way. 

It can only happen during build/publish.